# How to write shellscript to remove string begin with the specified word

Tags: shell-script

I have shellscript to run program like this

```
sudo swatchdog -c /home/pi/.swatchdogrc -t /var/log/snort/alert  >> /home/pi/swatch/output/a.txt
```

I have output of a.txt like this …

```
*** swatchdog version 3.2.4 (pid:2139) started at Sun 05 Jan 2020 05:16:17 PM +07

192.168.2.198

57312

192.168.2.238

22

192.168.2.198

57314

192.168.2.238
```

I want to remove this sentence `*** swatchdog version 3.2.4 (pid:2139) started at Sun 05 Jan 2020 05:16:17 PM +07` every time when it shows. How can I do this by writing a shellscript?
PS I also tried

```
cd swatch/output $ sudo swatchdog -c /home/pi/.swatcgdogrc -t /var/log/snort/alert | cut -c 82- > a.txt
```

But it doesn't print anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### grep

You can use `grep` with `-v` option which outputs your input excluding the line which contains specified keyword. From man page:

> -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines

```bsh
grep -v "keyword/pattern" file 

# Pipeline
command | grep -v "keyword/pattern" > output
```

So, your script would be:

```
sudo swatchdog -c /home/pi/.swatchdogrc -t /var/log/snort/alert | grep -v "swatchdog" >> /path/to/output.txt
```

### awk

You can also achieve the same result using `awk`

```bsh
awk '! /keyword/ {print}' file

# Pipeline
command | awk '! /keyword/ {print} > output
```

```bsh
sudo swatchdog -c /home/pi/.swatchdogrc -t /var/log/snort/alert | awk '! /swatchdog/ {print}' >> /path/to/output.txt
```